# iPhone OS: Sharing a UIWebView between ViewControllers in a UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am trying to create a application with a tab bar and a common WebView.

The different tabs shows/hides different divs in the WebView but maintain the state otherwise, so I need to share the web view between the tabs.

I am trying to use a nib, but I think that might not be the right solution here.

Any pointers for doing this correctly?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a UITabBarController, a UITabBar would suffice. You only need to assign it a delegate, and implement the `tabBar:didSelectItem:` delegate method.

Here's what I would do:

1. Create a view controller and add a UITabBar and a UIWebView
2. Set UITabBar's delegate to this view controller and implement `tabBar:didSelectItem:`
3. Show/hide divs as necessary in `tabBar:didSelectItem:`